# Lambda Expression to order (sort) my list collection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a list collection of class type and class contains the following properties.

```
class mymodel()
{
 public string Name{ get; set; }
 public string AMPM{ get; set; }
}
List<mymodel> mylist;
```

AMPM properties should contain "AM" or "PM" or "MIX" or "--"

I need to sort my list collection in such a way that AM values come in the top, then PM values ,then Mix, then "--" values

How can I order this list collection using Lambda?

Answer (score 5):

You can add another property.

```
class mymodel {
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string AMPM{ get; set; }
    public int AMPM_Sort {
        get {
            if (AMPM == "AM")   return 1;
            if (AMPM == "PM")   return 2;
            if (AMPM == "MIX")  return 3;
            if (AMPM == "--")   return 4;
            return 9;
        }
    }
}
List<mymodel> mylist;
var sorted = mylist.OrderBy(x => x.AMPM_Sort);
```

Comment: I would optimize your code and set the AMPM_Sort value when setting the AMPM string. The sorting will go faster for long list. (public string AMPM {get { return _ampm;} set { _ampm = value; _ampm_Sort = appropriate_value;}}

Comment: +1. made it very simple. Actually it was not that much simple

Answer (score 2):

Implement `IComparable<T>` on your class and in the `CompareTo()` override, define your order of precendence. Afterwards use Lambda expression as: `OrderBy(x => x);`

```
class mymodel : IComparable<mymodel>
{
    public string AMPM { get; set; }

    public int System.IComparable<mymodel>.CompareTo(mymodel other)
    {
        int MyVal = AMPM == "AM" ? 1 : AMPM == "PM" ? 2 : AMPM == "MIX" ? 3 : 4;
        int OtherVal = other.AMPM == "AM" ? 1 : other.AMPM == "PM" ? 2 : other.AMPM == "MIX" ? 3 : 4;

        return MyVal.CompareTo(OtherVal);
 }
```

}

Now you can simply do `mylist.OrderBy(x => x)`. Even a simple `mylist.Sort()` will do.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Maarten solution, I would optimize the sorting by doing that way

```
    class mymodel
    {
        private string _ampm;
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string AMPM
        {
            get { return _ampm; }
            set 
            {
                _ampm = value;
                AMPM_Sort = AppropriateSort();
            }
        }

        public int AMPM_Sort { get; private set; }

        private int AppropriateSort()
        {
            if (AMPM == "AM")  return 1;
            if (AMPM == "PM")  return 2;
            if (AMPM == "MIX") return 3;
            return AMPM == "--" ? 4 : 9;
        }
    }
}

List<mymodel> mylist;
var sorted = mylist.OrderBy(x => x.AMPM_Sort);
```

Comment: I've created a little test program to do a performance test on both version, and the results show that your changes make little difference in this case. Build as release, and run from the commandline. Source: http://pastebin.com/GESZ7CY0 Results: http://pastebin.com/mVa7ABtD

Comment: Well it depends on your application. If you have to sort a big list (100 000 items) a lot of times. You can consider this option. Otherwise, you are right, it is brain f*ck for nothing. I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You could write custom comparer to determine which value is higher or lower.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order your list with that parameters, you have to create a custom comparer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CustomComparer: IComparer<mymodel>
{
    public int Compare(mymodel x, mymodel y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            if (y == null)
                return 0;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        // Add the comparison rules.
        // return 0 if are equal.
        // Return -1 if the second is greater.
        // Return 1 if the first is greater
    }
}
```

And the sort call is:

```
List<mymodel> mylist;
CustomComparer cc = new CustomComparer();
mylist.Sort(cc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must override Equal & GetHashCode method of class, then you can sort it in a list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use extension method 'OrderBy' with lambda expression.

```
 var collection = new List<Mymodel> {new Mymodel {AMPM = "AM", Name = "Test1"},
        new Mymodel {AMPM = "PM", Name = "Test2"},
        new Mymodel {AMPM = "AM", Name = "Test3"},
        new Mymodel {AMPM = "PM", Name = "Test4"}};

        var sorted = collection.OrderBy(p => p.AMPM);
```